# PSPermGen getting full

Tags: java, tomcat7

I'm having a problem with BO application which runs out of memory and i see the below error in the BO logs:

```
PSPermGen       reserved 196608K, committed 24640K, used 24587K [0x000000007fff0000, 0x0000000081800000, 0x000000008bff0000)
  object space 24640K, 99% used
```

From the command

```
java.exe -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

i see

```
    uintx MaxPermSize                               = 67108864 
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 268435456       {product}
```

meanwhile from tocat configuration file setenv.bat i see:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

Could someone help me finding a solution. When app runs out of space some services stops.

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [JVM and Memory Usage - JRun server not using full PSPermGen allocation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529482/jvm-and-memory-usage-jrun-server-not-using-full-pspermgen-allocation)

Comment: i think no! My system has enogh ram memory. It seems a parameter misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running Tomcat?

You've configured the MaxPermSize setting in setenv.bat which is only going to make a difference if you're running Tomcat from the command prompt.

If you're running it as a service, you need to configure that setting in a different place.  It's done through the GUI from the tomcat7w.exe app.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Tomcat7w_monitor_application

Comment: i didn't configure anything. these are default values. Tomcat is running as a service. I'm little bit confused, are these parametters (i.e. MaxPermSize) attributes of JAVA or any application like tomcat or business object?

Comment: Yes and thats seems to be the problem, the default value is not large enough.  You need to increase the size of MaxPermSize, which is a JVM setting.  For Tomcat under Windows it's done through the tool I mentioned above.  If you add `-XX:MaxPermSize=384m` through that tool as a JVM option it should substantially increase the space available to the JVM for PermGen.

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround was applied:

1. Stop tomcat service
2. Edit server.xml which is found at path D:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\tomcat\conf  Disable compression in the server.xml 
   Value should be set to "off" where compression="on"
3. Restart Tomcat service

Following were the changes in server.xml file:

> Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  connectionTimeout="20000"
>   redirectPort="8443" **compression="off"  URIEncoding="UTF-8"
>   compressionMinSize="2048"  noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
>   compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text/json,application/json**